# Using iText-1.4.3 and iText-2.1.0 in one project

Tags: jakarta-ee, itext

I need to use iText-1.4.3.jar and iText-2.1.0.jar in a single project. It is a thin client application and if I use iText-2.1.0.jar I am getting some error in during printing a pdf file and without this jar I am getting an error in some text printing somewhere else. How can I solve this problem?

***Update:***

If I use iText-2.1.0.jar I am getting the error

> "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.lowagie.text.Image.plainWidth()F"

while printing pdf file. And without it I get

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation
>   problems: 
>   The method getHeight() is undefined for the type Rectangle The method getWidth() is undefined for the type Rectangle

Comment: Can you put example code of how you are using both libraries and the errors you're getting.

Comment: If I use iText-2.1.0.jar getting error "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.lowagie.text.Image.plainWidth()F" while printing pdf file. And without it "java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: The method getHeight() is undefined for the type Rectangle The method getWidth() is undefined for the type Rectangle"

Answer (score 0):

Some methods signatures changed in newer version.

1. Delete / Remove the older iText version 1.4.3
2. Replace the method call:
   `plainWidth() -> getPlainWidth()`